# Materialized View blocking sessions

Tags: sql, oracle, materialized-views

We have created a materialized view on Oracle 19c, but Insert/Update blocking session. Below is our materialized view:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MVIEW refresh force ON COMMIT as
Select P.Id QTable_Id, P.Tw_Id, P.NTable_Id,P.ROWID QTable_ROWID,M1.ROWID NTable_ROWID,SL1.ROWID SlTable_ROWID,SL2.ROWID SlTable2_ROWID,
       Case   When (P.NTable_Id Is Not Null)  Then M1.SlTable_Id
                     When (P.SlTable_Id Is Not Null) Then  P.SlTable_Id
                     Else ''  -- When there is no SlTable_id
       End As SlTable_Id ,
       Case When (P.NTable_Id Is Not Null) Then
       (
              Case
                     When (M1.Sh_Id Is Not Null) Then M1.Sh_Id 
                     When (M1.SlTable_Id Is Not Null) Then SL2.Sh_Id 
                     Else ''  
              End
        )
     When (P.SlTable_Id Is Not Null) Then
       (
              Case
                     When ( SL1.Sh_Id Is Not Null) Then SL1.Sh_Id 
                     Else ''  
             End
              )
      Else ''  End As Sh_Id
From QTable P, NTable M1,SlTable SL1,SlTable  Sl2
where
    P.NTable_Id = M1.Id(+)
and P.SlTable_Id=SL1.Id(+)
and M1.SlTable_Id=Sl2.Id(+)
```

Comment: "where and" is legal SQL?

Comment: @DavidG.Pickett  have corrected in the main question

Comment: You want the materialized view to refresh when a transaction commits.  That means it needs to process the materialized view log and update rows in the materialized view.  So clearly that requires locking and those locks can cause blocking for other sessions.  It's not clear whether you are just seeing the normal, expected blocking or if there is an actual problem.  If you don't need the MV to be transactionally consistent with the base tables, you could have it refresh on a schedule instead.  Otherwise, show us the `create table` and `create materialized view log` statements.

Comment: As an aside, there is no empty string separate from `null` in Oracle.  So something like `Case When ( SL1.Sh_Id Is Not Null) Then SL1.Sh_Id Else '' End` is exactly identical to just `sl1.sh_id`.

Comment: Did you already create any indexes on it ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 all these columns or either primary keys or foreign key.

Comment: With my experience we also need to create indexes for individual`rowid`(`QTable_ROWID,NTable_ROWID,SlTable_ROWID,SlTable2_ROWID`) on the materialized view which makes performance of the refresh faster. Could you try it.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 - Let me try and confirm. Meanwhile, is there a way to find out why its blocking session even with a single update statement

Comment: If its blocking we can look into sessions and may be v$sql to find out which query is running. There are ways and predefined queries we can get it from internet too. I have look my PC for those queries which is not possible now.